# Should this question be closed, deleted, self-answered, or what?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, deleted-questions, search

Here's a situation I face with one of my own questions:

[Delay signing during development and not on the build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132418/delay-signing-during-development-and-not-on-the-build-server)

I'm not sure what the hell to do with this.  My current plan is to eventually accept my own answer.

Right now, the question is on my record as being unanswered.  I wish this not to be the case.

I am not sure if I should delete it.  I don't believe deleted questions show in search results, but I want this question to show up in searches so that people looking for this information can get pointed to the correct solution.

I am not sure if it should be closed.  I don't know if closed answers show up in search results.  If they do, then closing is fine.  But I can't close it alone; I need other users to join with me.  This means my accept rate is lower than it would be if I could close it by myself.  If they don't show up in search results, then I don't want to close it.

In short, my goals are to:

- "Close" my question to further answers
- Remove the question from my list of unanswered questions
- Have my question come up in search results as a "signpost" for the correct answer

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave your question there and accept your answer with the link to the answer you found on the other question.

Comment: Is that always best?  It seems a bit cheesy...

Comment: And if you want to avoid the appearance of rep-gaming, you could make the answer wiki.

Comment: @Will -why cheesy?  You're providing a service to people who end up at your question.  I think it's perfectly legitimate.  I have a couple of questions where I've provided my own answer after having done a bit more research and I have no problem accepting them when they are the best answer to the question.