# Improving the acceptance criteria?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, accept-rate

How to improve the acceptance criteria in cases when you ask 2-3 questions and none have got a correct response which solves the issue. How is the acceptance criteria calculated, are all these things taken care of?

Although it's pretty sure that issue was fixed by the programmer, but may be not in a standard manner. So posting those answers may misguide the other users who come down in search of solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does accept rate work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

Comment: @lunboks i'm looking for a probable solution for my 2nd query..

Comment: @GhostRider: the accept rate is calculated using the criteria listed in the FAQ lunboks linked, that's it. It doesn't take into account the contents of the questions or answers at all - how could it? What are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Hard to parse this question, but it sounds like: "can I ask questions that nobody can answer and have it not affect my accept rate?"  No.

Comment: No matter *how* you solved the problem, standard manner or not, post your answer and accept it. It might attract some downvotes if it is truly a bad solution, but it'll still be there and be accepted.

Comment: Also possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38149/should-this-question-be-closed-deleted-self-answered-or-what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st question:

If your question not getting enough attention, then you can offer bounty for question. And accept answers which are giving some hints, giving way to solution or exact answer.

Ask yourself the following questions about question:

- Is the question tagged appropriately?
- Is the question too broad, or difficult to understand?
- Is the question missing key pieces of information that are needed to provide answers?
- Does the question show no effort on the part of the author?
- Would answering the question simply take more time than most people in our community care to spend?

2nd question:

Accept rate is calculated as:

- The accept rate is the percentage of answers accepted based on the questions asked by the user.
- The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.
- The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24hrs or more to update. (See below.)
- The accept rate is only calculated when the user has 4 or more questions.